# Logcat wraps text onto another line even though the 'Soft-Wrap' mode is off

Tags: android-studio

A weird thing concerning Logcat has happened to me today.

Up to this day, as I remember, every line has taken its full length (an indefinite one, practically) without running to the next line.

But now, even though the 'Soft-Wrap' mode is off, it jumps on the next line for the sake of the size of my screen, and I don't like it, as the stacktrace lines, for example, turn into mash that's hard to read:

[image: 1]

If I turn the 'Soft-Wrap' mode on, however, it gets even worse:

[image: 2]

What do I do? I have tried restarting Android Studio, restarting my PC, invalidating caches — to no avail.

Noteworthy, the same issue takes place in the `Run` tab, and in the `Build` tab as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If anyone will ever fall into the same trap as me, all you need to do is right-click on the very edge of the Logcat "content" window (where it ends and the toolbar panel begins) and uncheck "Soft-wrap".
[image: 1]

> I definitely turned this on by accident (and found the solution by accident, too, haha).

Note that the same solution would apply to tabs `Run` and `Build`.

Comment: Thanks @bighugedev, It is working fine for me